# Redirect old domain to new domain with same URL structure

Tags: domain, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, wordpress

I am trying to redirect URLs at my old WordPress domain to the same URL structure but at my new domain.

So for example:

- `oldsite.com/post-name-1` would redirect to `newsite.com/post-name-1`
- `oldsite.com/post-name-2` would redirect to `newsite.com/post-name-2` ... and so on.

I have tried adding the following to the `.htaccess` file under my old domain:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What rule do I need to write into my `.htaccess` file to achieve this?

Comment: The rule looks correct. What happens if you use it?

Comment: See https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress on how to move WordPress to a new domain.

Comment: Presumably `oldsite.com` and `newsite.com` don't currently point to the same place - so the redirect can be unconditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Redirect 301 / https://newsite.com/
```

See the docs for [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect). There's a tendency to use mod_rewrite for everything in Apache because it does so much, but this is one of those nice cases where the simple `Redirect` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

This would never work in a per-directory `.htaccess` file context because of the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. In a *directory* (or `.htaccess`) context the directory prefix (which notably ends with a slash) is first removed from the URL-path before the pattern matching occurs - so the matched URL-path *never starts with a slash*. As it stands, this directive is intended to be used in a *server* or *virtualhost* context.

In `.htaccess` you would need to remove the slash prefix (or make it optional):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, providing `oldsite.com` and `newsite.com` currently point to different hosts and the WordPress `.htaccess` directives have been removed from `oldsite.com` then you should implement an unconditional `Redirect` as @AndrewSchulman suggests.